# How to filter data in the table from Navbar (option wise filtering) in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

There are 2 components named `CollegeNavbar` and `AdminCollegeStudentTable`. I imported these two components in a `AdminCollegeStudentList.js` file. I want to filter data in the table using search button in the navbar( CollegeNavbar). How do I do that I tried using following approach can you give corrections in my code?

CollegeNavbar Component

```js
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import { Col, Row } from "reactstrap";

function CollegeNavbar(props) {
  // React state to manage selected options
  const [selectedOptions1, setSelectedOptions1] = useState();
  const [selectedOptions2, setSelectedOptions2] = useState();
  const [selectedOptions3, setSelectedOptions3] = useState();

  // Array of all options
  const optionList1 = [
    { value: "College", label: "SCOE" },
    { value: "College", label: "SKN" },
    { value: "College", label: "NBNSCOE" },
  ];
  const optionList2 = [
    { value: "dept", label: "CS" },
    { value: "dept", label: "IT" },
    { value: "dept", label: "ENTC" },
    { value: "dept", label: "MECHANICAL" },
    { value: "dept", label: "CIVIL" },
    { value: "dept", label: "CHEMICAL" },
    { value: "dept", label: "BIO-TECH" },
    { value: "dept", label: "PRODUCTION" },
  ];
  const optionList3 = [
    { value: "year", label: "FE" },
    { value: "year", label: "SE" },
    { value: "year", label: "TE" },
    { value: "year", label: "BE" },
  ];

  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");

  const handleFilterChange = (event) => {
    setFilter(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleFilterClick = () => {
    props.onFilter(filter);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Row className="px-3">
        <Col className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-11 text-center my-2 px-0 align-self-center">
          <Row className="mx-0 ">
            <Col className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-4 pr-3">
              <div id="collegename" className="dropdown-container">
                <Select
                  options={optionList1}
                  placeholder="College Name"
                  value={selectedOptions1}
                  onChange={() => setSelectedOptions1}
                  isSearchable={true}
                  isClearable
                />
              </div>
            </Col>
            <Col className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-4 px-3">
              <div id="branchname" className="dropdown-container">
                <Select
                  options={optionList2}
                  placeholder="Branch Name"
                  value={selectedOptions2}
                  onChange={() => setSelectedOptions2}
                  isSearchable={true}
                  isClearable
                />
              </div>
            </Col>
            <Col className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-4 px-3">
              <div id="curryear" className="dropdown-container">
                <Select
                  options={optionList3}
                  placeholder="Current Year"
                  value={selectedOptions3}
                  onChange={() => setSelectedOptions3}
                  isSearchable={true}
                  isClearable
                />
              </div>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Col>
        <Col className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-1 text-center my-2 px-0">
          <Button
            onClick={handleFilterClick}
            onChange={handleFilterChange}
            variant="outline-success"
            size="lg"
          >
            Search
          </Button>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </>
  );
}

export default CollegeNavbar;
```

AdminCollegeStudentTable Component

```js
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom/cjs/react-router-dom.min";

function AdminCollegeStudentTable(props) {
  const [myData, setMyData] = useState([]);
  const [deletedRecords, setDeletedRecords] = useState([]);
  const [lastAction, setLastAction] = useState("");
  const [sortOrder, setSortOrder] = useState("asc");
  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);

  //using promises
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3006/StudentList") //This works only for .json and .js file
      .then((response) => setMyData(response.data));
  }, []);

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    const confirmation = window.confirm(
      "Are you sure you want to delete this record?"
    );
    if (confirmation) {
      const deletedRecord = myData.find((alumni) => alumni.id === id);
      axios.delete(`http://localhost:3006/StudentList/${id}`).then(() => {
        setMyData(myData.filter((alumni) => alumni.id !== id));
        setDeletedRecords([...deletedRecords, deletedRecord]);
        setLastAction("delete");
        alert(
          "Record deleted successfully! Click Undo button to undo the delete operation."
        );
      });

      // Sort the table by id in ascending order after deleting record
      const sortedData = [...myData].sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
      setMyData(sortedData);
    }
  };

  const handleUndo = () => {
    if (lastAction === "delete") {
      const restoredRecord = deletedRecords[deletedRecords.length - 1];
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:3006/StudentList", restoredRecord)
        .then(() => {
          setMyData([...myData, restoredRecord]);
          setDeletedRecords(deletedRecords.slice(0, -1));
          setLastAction("undo");
        });

      // Sort the table by id in ascending order after re-deleting record
      const sortedData = myData.slice(0, -1).sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
      setMyData(sortedData);
    } else if (lastAction === "undo") {
      const reDeletedRecord = myData[myData.length - 1];
      axios
        .delete(`http://localhost:3006/StudentList/${reDeletedRecord.id}`)
        .then(() => {
          setMyData(myData.slice(0, -1));
          setDeletedRecords([...deletedRecords, reDeletedRecord]);
          setLastAction("delete");
        });

      // Sort the table by id in ascending order after re-deleting record
      const sortedData = myData.slice(0, -1).sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
      setMyData(sortedData);
    }
  };

  const handleSort = (field) => {
    const sortedData = [...myData].sort((a, b) => {
      if (sortOrder === "asc") {
        return a[field] < b[field] ? -1 : 1;
      } else {
        return b[field] < a[field] ? -1 : 1;
      }
    });

    setMyData(sortedData);
    setSortOrder(sortOrder === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc");
  };

  const handleFilter = (filterValue) => {
    const filteredStudents = students.filter((student) => {
      return (
        student.college.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue.toLowerCase()) ||
        student.branch.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue.toLowerCase()) ||
        student.year.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue.toLowerCase())
      );
    });
    setStudents(filteredStudents);
  };

  return (
    <Table striped bordered hover responsive onChange={handleFilter}>
      <Link
        onClick={handleUndo}
        className="btn btn-info"
        disabled={myData.length === 0 && deletedRecords.length === 0}
      >
        Undo
      </Link>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th onClick={() => handleSort("id")}>Sr.No</th>
          <th onClick={() => handleSort("name")}>Name</th>
          <th onClick={() => handleSort("college")}>College name</th>
          <th onClick={() => handleSort("branch")}>Branch name</th>
          <th onClick={() => handleSort("year")}>Year</th>
          <th>Profile</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {myData.map((student) => (
          <tr key={student.id}>
            <td>{student.id}</td>
            <td>{student.name}</td>
            <td>{student.college}</td>
            <td>{student.branch}</td>
            <td>{student.year}</td>
            <td>
              <Link
                to={`/student/${student.id}`}
                className="btn btn-primary sm"
              >
                View Profile
              </Link>
            </td>
            <td>
              <Link
                onClick={() => handleDelete(student.id)}
                className="btn btn-danger sm"
              >
                Delete
              </Link>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  );
}

export default AdminCollegeStudentTable;
```

AdminCollegeStudentList.js where I used above components

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import CollegeNavbar from "components/Navbars/CollegeNavbar";
import AdminCollegeStudentTable from "components/Tables/AdminCollegeStudentTable";

// reactstrap components
import { Card, CardHeader, CardBody, Row, Col } from "reactstrap";

function AdminCollegeStudents() {
  const [filterValue, setFilterValue] = useState("");

  const handleFilterChange = (event) => {
    setFilterValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="content">
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <div className="CollegeNav">
              <CollegeNavbar handleFilterChange={handleFilterChange} />
            </div>
            <Card>
              <CardHeader>
                <h1 className="title">Students</h1>
              </CardHeader>
              <CardBody className="all-icons">
                <AdminCollegeStudentTable filterValue={filterValue} />
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default AdminCollegeStudents;
```

Comment: Your `onChange` in the `CollegeNavbar` component seems the be a bit off try `onChange={setSelectedOption1}` instead of `onChange={() => setSelectedOption1}`. The setState is not getting a value otherwise

Comment: I tried that but it still not working